# Why do we need to pass a color to each vertex?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I read the book opengl es 2.0 a quick start by kevin brothaler.

He wrote a vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec4 a_Color;
varying vec4 v_Color;
void main()
{
    v_Color = a_Color;
    gl_Position = a_Position;
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
```

and a fragment shader like this:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 v_Color;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = v_Color;
}
```

My question: Why do we need to pass a color to vertex shader? Cant we just pass color to fragment shader directly? And it says that vertex shader is for vertices positions only and fragment shader is for fragment colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a colour directly to the fragment shader using an uniform. This colour is then per draw call (per object). On the other hand you can pass a colour per vertex which begins in the vertex shaders and is then passed to the fragment shader.

While the first procedure is quite straight forward the second is not. If you are passing the colour per vertex you must use an attribute. Each and every vertex then needs to have a colour attribute. How this colours are then used depends on the vertex shader but generally these colours will be interpolated per fragment in the rasterisation. How this works for instance is: You draw a line with 2 points one having a white colour and the other having a black colour. The result you will see will be a gradient line from white to black (grey in  between). Same goes for triangles (try 3 vertices having red, green and blue colours). This used to be a most common test (tutorial) application by the way; an openGL version of "hello world".

Which of these 2 you will implement really depends on your needs and in many cases both of them are used and multiplied in the fragment shader.

The `varying` values are used to pass to the fragment shader from the vertex shader. That means any value you wish for it to be interpolated per fragment must be used this way. What you need to do is define such a value in the vertex shader and then you can use it in the fragment shader. The two definitions are similar, not much to say about it but you can think of it as using `extern` though there is much more going on in the back.

The colour interpolation is indeed a bad example for someone learning because you usually find no use for it. An extremely common usage of such interpolation are normals. If you want do draw a nice curved surface using lighting you want to interpolate the normals so the shape does not look too edgy.

Comment: Thanks @matic oblak. But cant i use attributes to fragment shader?
And also, the variable "varying vec4 v_Color;" is present in the fragment shader and vertex shader. Is that variable treated as the same? I mean global variable?

Comment: No, that variable is in vertex shader so you set a specific value to it which is defined per vertex. Then after the raster (fragments are made) these values are interpolated by taking 2 or more vertices (depending on the shape you are drawing). What you get in that value in fragment shader is the result of that interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

No, we do not need to pass any colors to vertex shader, the only requirement is that fragment shader have to store output value or discard the fragment.
Most commonly this output is stored in gl_FragColor variable.

Vertex shader could pass some color value to fragment shader, that could be transfered from some attribute, lighting could be performed or nearly whatever shader developer wants.

Fragment shader could calculate output color using any and all its input data, in simplest case could just pass some constant or uniform (provided by calling code) value.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. And also, this troubled in my mind. why do both shaders have the same variable "varying vec4 v_Color";

Comment: Value stored into v_Color in vertex shader is interpolated between vertices and this interpolated value is accessible in fragment shader. In basic words those variables are connected during link stage, vertex's one is writable and fragment's is readable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I now understand.
And we can also pass a uniform value to fragment shader right using gluniform4f()? im pointing to gles 2.0.